# What's the difference between map[type] interface{} and type struct {}?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I just read that map[Type]interface{} specifies a map of keys of type Type with values any i.e. interface{}.

Isn't this almost the same as defining a structure i.e. type Name struct{ key1; value1, ...., keyn: valuen}?

What is the difference between those two types of mappings?

I read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-json-in-go but I still don't get the difference.

Or is the difference that with map[type] interface{} we define in a more general way?

And with struct we define each key value pair?

And both of them are just ways to define objects which consist of key value pairs?

Comment: "And both of them are just ways to define objects which consist of key value pairs?" - that's one way to think about it. But structs are more powerful than just a simple mapping (can have methods, implement interfaces, etc.). If you have a known and fixed set keys (and types for their values), you should probably use a struct.

Comment: Maps, just like arrays and slices, can have elements of only one and the same (static) type. Structs don't have that limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs and maps are different data structures. They have many differences. Here are just a few:

A struct has a fixed number of fields that are declared once and can't change.

```
point := struct{ x, y float64 }{
    x: 1.0,
    y: 1.0,
}
```

A map can grow or shrink at runtime.

```
vector := map[string]float64{
    "x": 2.0,
    "y": 2.0,
}

vector["z"] = 2.0
```

You can loop over map entries.

```
for key, val := range vector {
    fmt.Println(key, val)
}
```

Structs don't support iteration (unless you use reflection).

Struct fields can have tags (additional attributes):

```
type User struct {
    Name          string    `json:"name"`
    Password      string    `json:"password"`
}
```

Maps don't have this feature.